# How to add imported image to formData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, file, form-data

I need to send the imported image as a file. I try to add it into `new File()` but it will not recognize the type and correct size of image and i can't send i to backend

```
import img from '../image.png';
...
const image= new File([img], "img.png");

console.log(image) // 
lastModified: 1590023609558
lastModifiedDate: Thu May 21 2020 05:13:29 GMT+0400 (Armenia Standard Time) {}
name: "img.png"
size: 41 //(my real file size is 124KB)
type: ""
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

Comment: is it correct actually with `../image.PMG`??

Comment: it's my typo. sorry. but it still doesn't work

Comment: do you have it setup to be able to import an image. this is not a standard import. if you re in node it would be best to open the file with fs.readFile().  if in the browser it is a little more complicated

Comment: It's React application. I'm not in node, I just need to send file, no care what to do with file in backend.